# Create kmz file out of Illustrator maps?

Tags: kmz, illustrator

I'm migrating my ERP from an old-style mapping system which relied on jpg files and coordinates on the file to locate my assets, to a vectored system which uses KMZ files.

I'm new to this - I'm here sitting with my illustrator files and I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Did you generate the jpegs from vector graphics in Illustrator (adobe?), or were you manipulating the jpegs in Illustrator?

Comment: Illustrator is a vector Adobe application. It is possibile to convert .ai file to DWG/shapefile and then to KML/Z. See previous answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/adobe-illustrator-file-conversion-viewer-question

Comment: "map" files are generated in Illustrator - proper .ai format. The link uses GIS software, which is quite expensive given what I'm trying to do. Any alternative?

Comment: Breaking it down - there are a couple of approaches to translate .ai files into DWG - see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/how-to-import-a-dwg-into-a-qgis-project from there, you could get a copy of QGIS (qgis.org) and run DWG to KML/Z from there. The added bonus of doing that is you could check the validity of the DWGs in QGIS prior to conversion (ie. do they relate to the right locations - have fun!